# Getting list of dates (excluding weekends)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, date

I am using python v3.6. I would like to get a list of dates that exclude weekends.

Here is what I have on hand;

```
import pandas as pd
datelist = pd.bdate_range(pd.datetime.today(), periods=10).tolist()
```

What the above code does is to return a list of dates starting from today to next 10 days.

How do I conveniently specify the starting date in the format `dd/mm/yyyy` to get this range? I would like to be able to do something like this;

```
datelist = pd.bdate_range(function_format_date("01/10/2017"), periods=10).tolist()
```

Comment: Hey, I didn't know `pd.bdate_range('21/12/2017', periods=10).tolist()` already works! Should have tried that out before asking. Stupid me.

Comment: @Zero, you could post your comment as answer. I will upvote and mark it as correct answer. For future reference. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do

```
pd.bdate_range('21/12/2017', periods=10).tolist()
```

Or, be more specific with `pd.to_datetime(.., format=)`

```
pd.bdate_range(pd.to_datetime('21/12/2017', format='%d/%m/%Y'), periods=10).tolist()
```